# How to handle change event of dropdownlist in mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have dropdownlist in parent view and also have multiple partial views. When user change the value of dropdown,all the partial value should change according to new value in dropdown. Please have a look on my script. I think there is something missing.

When page first loads, I am using the ActionResult which is same when dropdown change event executes. So the same ActionResult calling twice.

Error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

Model

```
public class ClsA
{  public string Country{get;set;}      
    public List<first> firsts{ get; set; }    
    public List<second> seconds{ get; set; }
    public List<third> thirds{ get; set; }
}

public class first
{     
    public string NameId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

}

public class second
{
    public string Details{ get; set; }
    public string Age{ get; set; }             
}

public class third
{
    public string occupation{ get; set; }
    public string company{ get; set; }             
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ABC(string countrylist)
 {
   SDetails sDetails=new SDetails(); 
   string nameid = sDetails.Rst(countrylist).FirstOrDefault().NameId;       
   var model = new ClsA();
   model.firsts = sDetails.Rst(countrylist);            
   model.seconds = sDetails.Rs(nameid); 
   model.thirds = sDetails.Ss(nameid);  
   return View(model);
 }
```

View

```
@model Aplication.Models.ABC.ClsA     
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, new List<SelectListItem>
{                       
    new SelectListItem {Value = "NP", Text="NLand" },
    new SelectListItem {Value = "MS", Text = "MaLand"},    
},new { @id = "CountryList"})

<div id=myA>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialA", Model.firsts); }
</div>
<div id=myB>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialB", Model.seconds);} 
</div>
<div id=myC>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialC", Model.thirds);} 
</div>
```

Script

```
  $('#CountryList').change(function () {
                var countrylist = $(this).val();
                var url = '@Url.Action("ABC", "ABC")';
                $('#myA').load(url, { countrylist: countrylist });
                $('#myB').load(url, { countrylist: countrylist });
                $('#myC').load(url, { countrylist: countrylist });
            });
```

_PartialA

```
@model  IEnumerable<Aplication.Models.ABC.first>

    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.NameId)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Address)</th>            
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameId)
                </td>
                <td>                   
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)                    
                </td>                

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

_PartialB

```
@model  IEnumerable<Aplication.Models.ABC.second>

    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Details)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Age)</th>            
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Details)
                </td>
                <td>                   
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)                    
                </td>                

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

_PartialC

```
@model  IEnumerable<Aplication.Models.ABC.third>

    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.occupation)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.company)</th>            
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.occupation)
                </td>
                <td>                   
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.company)                    
                </td>                

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: Your `ABC()` method does not accept a value for `countrylist`. All you are doing is getting the identical partial views each time you select an option.

Comment: I assume what you want is `public ActionResult ABC(string countrylist)` and then you want `model.firsts = sDetails.Rst(countrylist);`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I want to load the partials based on dropdown list value selection.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I updated the controller.

Comment: The you need a method that has a parameter for the selected option. but that method is returning the whole view - so you are adding the whole view 3 times inside each of your `<div>`'s

Comment: Can you please guide me with solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170772/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user9895).